# Making complex-shape volumetrics

Tags: animation, mesh, volumetrics

I'm trying to create a fog in the shape of infinity symbol (ထ).
Another goal is to animate it flowing cyclically.

I managed to achieve this on the surface of a mesh, but failed when trying to apply it to the mesh's volume. The main problem is making volumetrics follow mesh shape.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

answer for version 3.3 alpha (and sorry, yes, i nearly always work with the newest alpha version):

Make a curve (like a 8 or whatever), add the GN node tree:

[image]

result:

[image]

Comment: .. maybe we need a version number with this answer? .. 3.3 is still alpha..

Comment: ok, added that information.     ;)